# Dynamic Ranges in two workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to compare a column in a master sheet to a column in sheet that is being opened via a request box. I would like the ranges to be dynamic compared to what I have currently in the code. In the master sheet I would like for it to look a column A starting in cell A2 and go to the last entry and in the opened sheet it should look at column E starting in cell C2 and go to the last entry. Code I am currently using is below:

```
Sub InspectionCheck()

 Dim colI_Cell As Range
 Dim colI_Range As Range
 Dim rngLookupRange As Range
 Dim rngFound As Range
 Dim rngInspected As Range
 Dim FileName As Variant
 Dim wb As Workbook

Set colI_Range = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A350").Cells
FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files(*.xlsx),*.xlsx")
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName)

Set rngLookupRange = wb.Worksheets("owssvr").Range("E2:E350")
ThisWorkbook.Activate

For Each colI_Cell In colI_Range
With rngLookupRange
  Set rngFound = .Find(What:=colI_Cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
  If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
   colI_Cell.Offset(0, 1) = "Yes"
  Else: colI_Cell.Offset(0, 1) = "No"

  End If
End With
Next


Set rngLookupRange = Nothing
wb.Close False
Set wb = Nothing
Set colI_Range = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What problem has your code? Where did you get stuck? Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite easily done if you use the following module code to find the  last row that is not blank:

```
Function FindLastRowNotBlank(ByRef ws As Worksheet, ByRef firstRow As Long, _ 
ByRef column As Long) As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = firstRow
If ws.Cells(lastRow, column).Value <> "" Then
    Do While ws.Cells(lastRow, column).Value <> ""
        lastRow = lastRow + 1
    Loop
    FindLastRowNotBlank = lastRow - 1 'the last entry is the blank row so needs to subtract 1 from the result
Else
    FindLastRowNotBlank = 0 'Returns 0 if the firstRow is empty
    Exit Function
End If
End Function
```

Then you can use the number obtained in your code like this:

```
Sub InspectionCheck()

Dim colI_Cell As Range
Dim colI_Range As Range
Dim rngLookupRange As Range
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim rngInspected As Range
Dim FileName As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim i as Long, rngStr as String

i = FindLastRowNotBlank(ActiveSheet, 2,1) 'I have added this
rngStr = "A2:A" & i 'I have added this
Set colI_Range = ActiveSheet.Range(rngStr).Cells 'I have modified this
FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files(*.xlsx),*.xlsx")

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName)

i = FindLastRowNotBlank(wb.Worksheets("yoursheetnamehere"), 2,5) 'I have added this you need to fill in the worksheet name
rngStr = "E2:E" & i 'I have added this
Set rngLookupRange = wb.Worksheets("owssvr").Range(rngStr) ' I have modified this
ThisWorkbook.Activate

For Each colI_Cell In colI_Range
With rngLookupRange
  Set rngFound = .Find(What:=colI_Cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
    colI_Cell.Offset(0, 1) = "Yes"
Else: colI_Cell.Offset(0, 1) = "No"

End If
End With
Next


Set rngLookupRange = Nothing
wb.Close False
Set wb = Nothing
Set colI_Range = Nothing

End Sub
```

Let me know how it works. Thanks,
Clint